# Web Cam Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, webcam

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 but for some reason my webcam is not working. I've tried different softwares as cheese, GUVCVIEW and Camorama. Nothing work. When trying GUVCVIEW I have the message "no video device found". Cheese gives me as output: There was an error playing video from webcam. After trying a lots of different things, I have this now: [Error GUVCVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrsnn.png) When click OK, I can save a video when I can capture the audio, but not the image

When typing lsusb the output I have is this: [lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrAUr.png)

webcam ubuntu-18.04

Comment: Does `sudo lshw` show it? Look at the group ownership of `/dev/vid*` (`ls -l /dev/vid*`). `id` will show your current group memberships. Add yourself to `/dev/vid*`s group with `adduser`

Comment: I got it! I had to reinstall Ubuntu and now it is working.thanks

Comment: @waltinator, sudo lshw shows many things. What is the "it" that I am looking for?

Comment: @waltinator. how does one add oneself? and to what? can you kindly post a solution?

Comment: @waltinator, when I type, "ls -l /dev/vid*", I get two lines of response:      crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jan 14 08:00 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jan 14 08:00 /dev/video1   What does this tell me?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/video0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.